# How to speed up counting and filtering on table with a lot of columns and filter conditions?

Tags: sql, indexing, count, sql-optimization

I have TABLE_A in my database that has a lot of columns.

Let's say there are 100 columns: COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3, .. COLUMN_100

My Application should do the following tasks:

- Receive a set of filter conditions from the user
- Execute a query in the database that filters the data on given conditions and then should count the result rows

There are no limits on the number of filter conditions:

- there may be no filter conditions
- there may be filter conditions on every column of the table
- there may be filter conditions on some columns of the table (for example on 50 columns out of all)

So below is an example query that my application executes:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    TABLE_A 
WHERE 
    COLUMN_1 = 'test'
    AND COLUMN_2 != 'q'
    AND COLUMN_45 > 5
    AND COLUMN_45 < 511
    AND COLUMN_92 LIKE '%ddd%'
    AND COLUMN_98 > 1000
```

TABLE_A doesn't have any indexes - each column can be used for filtering, so I understand only composite index for all columns can help somehow but it will slow the insert and update operations.

I also don't use any kind of cache on any level: insert and update operations happen not very often but more often than at least 2 query with the same filter conditions occur.

So in case of every query the sequential search is executed. It was not a problem earlier, but now the run-times of the query became unacceptable (number of rows in the table increased a lot).

So..

**Is there any solution on how to speed up the execution of the task?**

Any suggestions would be appreciated - I can change anything except one thing - I should use SQL.

Comment: Maybe https://dba.stackexchange.com/ is more suitable place for this question

Comment: What RDBMS do you want to use ?

Comment: "*so I understand only composite index for all columns can help*" - on the contrary. Typically the databases can only use the leading columns of an index (efficiently). So if at all you'd need one index for each column. But this can't be answered without knowing which DBMS you are using. Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

That many columns in a table is usually indicative of a denormalised design, and the performance issues you're seeing tend to follow. My first suggestion would be to see if you can normalise the table. Composite indexes will likely not help you here as the key order is important & will only help for a very small subset of queries. However, if there is a set of queries that are run much more frequently than the rest you could create suitable indexes for those to help the most common ones.